# How to scrape different pages of an unchanging Url that pages change with tabs on the top bar of Url?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to parse this page 'http://www.tsetmc.ir/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=22811176775480091' ,but it has a tab_bar on top ,so when I click one of them it shows up new information ,but with the same url.
I am using BeautifulSoup & selenium to parse that but i can't find the tag on the pages that are shown when i click one of the tabs.
[This image shows the tabs that i mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtHuS.png)

Comment: show your code trials and errors

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could see, this menu uses classes, so you have to write:

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector(class="...").click()`- with this one he will click on the object with the class name you put into the parentheses.

A small example: 
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector(class="yellow").click()`
The driver would click on the yellow tab, and would open it in the same window.